# How to extract this computed ref into a reusable function?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am successfully using a Vue 3 Computed ref to return a different Firebase `doc` depending if a `currentAuditId` value is `undefined` or not.

Now I want to extract that functionality into a reusable function. But when I do that the computed ref stops working.

This Computed ref works. The `console.log` first prints `undefined` and then later prints the `currentAuditId`:

```TypeScript
const auditSource = computed(() => {
  console.log(user.value?.currentAuditId); // Prints 'undefined' initially, and then later it updates and prints the correct currentAuditId string
  if (user.value?.currentAuditId) {
    return doc(collection(firestore, "audits"), user.value?.currentAuditId);
  } else {
    return doc(collection(firestore, "audits"));
  }
});

const audit = useDocument<Audit>(auditSource);
```

But when I try to exact the computed ref into a reusable function, the computed ref no longer updates. The `console.log` prints `undefined` and then nothing else:

```TypeScript
const computedDoc = (collectionPath: string, documentId?: string) => {
  return computed(() => {
    console.log(documentId); // Prints 'undefined', and does not update again after that!
    if (documentId) {
      return doc(collection(firestore, collectionPath), documentId);
    } else {
      return doc(collection(firestore, collectionPath));
    }
  });
};

const audit = useDocument<Audit>(
  computedDoc("audits", user.value?.currentAuditId)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A computed sets up the dependencies at the time when it's calculated. Accessing `user.value?.currentAuditId` early will prevent it from working because `documentId` is non-reactive value.

In order to match the original code it should accept reactive value as an input, i.e. a ref:

```
const useComputedDoc = (collectionPath: string, documentIdRef: Ref<string>) => {
  return computed(() => {
    const documentId = unref(documentIdRef);
    ...
  });
};

const auditId = computed(() => user.value?.currentAuditId);
const auditDoc = useComputedDoc("audits", auditId);
const audit = useDocument<Audit>(auditDoc);
```

Two composables can be composed like:

```
const useComputedDocument = <T>(
  collectionPath: string,
  documentIdRef: Ref<string>
) => {
  const computedDoc = computed(() => {
    const documentId = unref(documentIdRef);
    if (documentId) {
      return doc(collection(firestore, collectionPath), documentId);
    } else {
      return doc(collection(firestore, collectionPath));
    }
  });

  return useDocument<T>(computedDoc);
};

const auditId = computed(() => user.value?.currentAuditId);
const audit = useComputedDocument<Audit>("audits", auditId);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But is it possible to abstract everything away into a single function?

Comment: No. You could reduce it to `useComputedDoc("audits", () => user.value?.currentAuditId)` and call this function internally, but a properly designed composable usually accepts a ref, this is the case ref pattern is intended for. You could combine it with useDocument if that's what you need

Comment: Can you update the answer to show me how to combine it with useDocument? I've been trying on my own but I don't understand it enough to get it working

Answer (score 0):

Try using ref() or reactive instead of computed. I guess it's a timing problem that your documentId is undefined. Computed is called before the variable is assigned. I would not return a computed function inside a function. I was using computed a lot in Vue2 but now in Vue3 I use ref or reactive instead. Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: "I would not return a computed function inside a function" - computedDoc is actually a composable, this usage is legit